# clicking on the dynamically created edit button is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4GP9c/215/) in which there is a form which accepts name,email and mobile number.After pressing the add button new records are inserted below the add button along with 2 bootstrap icons edit and delete.So when clicked on edit button it should display  column values(this only occurs for 1st 2 rows ) but when edit button is clicked on the newly created records then it does not display anything.Can I know where is the error?

this is the jquery code for edit button click

```
$('.icon-edit').click(function () {
      //alert("hi");
        $('#editReords').modal({show:true})
var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
var $columns = $row.find('td');
        //$columns.addClass('row-highlight');

        var values = "";
        jQuery.each($columns, function(i, item) {
            values =item.innerHTML;
            if(i==1){

                alert("name:"+values);
                //document.getElementById("name1").value = values;
            }
            else if(i==2){
                alert("emailID:"+values);
                //document.getElementById("date1").value = values;
            }
else if(i==3){
                alert("mobile:"+values);
                //document.getElementById("StartTime1").value = values;
            }});
    });
    $('#save').click(function () {
//alert("data saved");
    });
//edit records
    });
```

Comment: delegate event to the closest static container

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `on()` to delegate the event, because the elements are added dynamically:

```
$('.icon-edit').click(function () {
```

Should become:

```
$("#mytable").on('click', '.icon-edit', function () {
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4GP9c/224/)

Note: You can also use `delegate()` for this:

```
$("#mytable").delegate('.icon-edit', 'click', function() {
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4GP9c/226/)

Comment: No problem. Glad to have helped.

Comment: can I use every where $("#someId").on('click', '.some classt', function () { instead of $('.icon-edit').click(function () {
for button event

Comment: see when I click the edit button it displays name:entered name,email:enetered email and for mobile it displays some extra lines.how can I get only mobile

Comment: yeh it looks like another question,If you dont mind can you please provide a solution for this?

Comment: One solution is to change `values=item.innerHTML;` to `values=$(item).text();` on line 43. Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4GP9c/227/) for it.

Comment: Thanks again,I have been trying since morning for this problem

Answer (score 3):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

As elements are added dynamically you can not bind events directly to them .So you have to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```
$('#mytable').on('click','.icon-edit',function () { ..//code here })
```

Syntax

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/4GP9c/225/)</kbd>

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddle,Thanks for the answer +1

Comment: @javaBeginner Welocme Happy to help :)

Comment: can I use $( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
every where for click button events

Comment: @javaBeginner yes you can it's delegation .But i recommend only with elements added dynamically See-> http://jsperf.com/jquery-on-versus-click/2

Comment: When the edit button is clicked then for name and email values are okay but for mobile the alert is showing some thing extra.can you please tell me how to get only the entered mobile number?

Answer (score 0):

Oh sry ! I had a mistake to code
use this :

Try this code please :

```
$('#mytable').on('click','.icon-edit',function () {
      //alert("hi");
        $('#editReords').modal({show:true})
var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
var $columns = $row.find('td');
        //$columns.addClass('row-highlight');

        var values = "";
        jQuery.each($columns, function(i, item) {
            values =item.innerHTML;
            if(i==1){

                alert("name:"+values);
                //document.getElementById("name1").value = values;
            }
            else if(i==2){
                alert("emailID:"+values);
                //document.getElementById("date1").value = values;
            }
else if(i==3){
                alert("mobile:"+values);
                //document.getElementById("StartTime1").value = values;
            }});
    });
    $('#save').click(function () {
//alert("data saved");
    });
//edit records
    });
```

Comment: dont post 2 different answers.Delete one